# How to remove Form Feed from file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have created a script which is used to extract a certain section of data from the file, which works properly. But in the specific data which I want to extract Form Feed and in next line [] is present which I don't want. 
The Form Feed which appear in the file is:-

`['STAAD', 'SPACE', '--', 'PAGE', 'NO.', '']`

```py
import csv
found_type = False

filename = (r'C:\Users\GURBHEJ SINGH\Desktop\3d_frame.txt')
with open(filename, 'r') as f:

    for line in f:
        if line == '\n':
            continue

        if '0.00  MAX' in line:

            found_type = True

        if found_type:
            if '|---------------------------------------------------------------------------' in line:
               found_type = False

            else:
                t_line = str(line)
                t_line = list(t_line.split())
                print(t_line)
```

At some positions in the result From feed and in next line `[]` is present which I don't want like as shown below

```
['STAAD', 'SPACE', '--', 'PAGE', 'NO.', '8']
[]
```

To elaborate my problem I am giving a short part of the data I want which is from the file I used.

```
FILE

     2     0.00  MAX    64.08    2      6.17    2      0.00    2      0.00    2
                 MIN    42.72    1      4.11    1      0.00    2      0.00    2
     STAAD SPACE                                              -- PAGE NO.    6

           0.31  MAX    54.23    2     12.04    2      0.00    2      0.00    2
                 MIN    36.15    1      8.02    1      0.00    2      0.00    2
           0.62  MAX    44.37    2     27.20    2      0.00    2      0.00    2
                 MIN    29.58    1     18.14    1      0.00    2      0.00    2
           0.92  MAX    34.51    2     39.34    2      0.00    2      0.00    2
                 MIN    23.00    1     26.23    1      0.00    2      0.00    2
           1.23  MAX    24.65    2     48.44    2      0.00    2      0.00    2
                 MIN    16.43    1     32.29    1      0.00    2      0.00    2
           1.54  MAX    14.79    2     54.51    2      0.00    2      0.00    2
                 MIN     9.86    1     36.34    1      0.00    2      0.00    2
           1.85  MAX     4.93    2     57.54    2      0.00    2      0.00    2
                 MIN     3.29    1     38.36    1      0.00    2      0.00    2
           2.15  MAX     4.93    2     57.54    2      0.00    2      0.00    2
                 MIN     3.29    1     38.36    1      0.00    2      0.00    2
           2.46  MAX    14.79    2     54.51    2      0.00    2      0.00    2
                 MIN     9.86    1     36.34    1      0.00    2      0.00    2
           2.77  MAX    24.65    2     48.44    2      0.00    2      0.00    2
                 MIN    16.43    1     32.29    1      0.00    2      0.00    2
           3.08  MAX    34.51    2     39.34    2      0.00    2      0.00    2
                 MIN    23.00    1     26.23    1      0.00    2      0.00    2
           3.38  MAX    44.37    2     27.20    2      0.00    2      0.00    2
                 MIN    29.58    1     18.14    1      0.00    2      0.00    2
           3.69  MAX    54.23    2     12.04    2      0.00    2      0.00    2
                 MIN    36.15    1      8.02    1      0.00    2      0.00    2
           4.00  MAX    42.72    1      4.11    1      0.00    2      0.00    2
                 MIN    64.08    2      6.17    2      0.00    2      0.00    2


     3     0.00  MAX    64.08    2      6.17    2      0.00    2      0.00    2
                 MIN    42.72    1      4.11    1      0.00    2      0.00    2
           0.31  MAX    54.23    2     12.04    2      0.00    2      0.00    2
                 MIN    36.15    1      8.02    1      0.00    2      0.00    2
           0.62  MAX    44.37    2     27.20    2      0.00    2      0.00    2
                 MIN    29.58    1     18.14    1      0.00    2      0.00    2
           0.92  MAX    34.51    2     39.34    2      0.00    2      0.00    2
                 MIN    23.00    1     26.23    1      0.00    2      0.00    2
           1.23  MAX    24.65    2     48.44    2      0.00    2      0.00    2
                 MIN    16.43    1     32.29    1      0.00    2      0.00    2
           1.54  MAX    14.79    2     54.51    2      0.00    2      0.00    2
                 MIN     9.86    1     36.34    1      0.00    2      0.00    2
           1.85  MAX     4.93    2     57.54    2      0.00    2      0.00    2
                 MIN     3.29    1     38.36    1      0.00    2      0.00    2
           2.15  MAX     4.93    2     57.54    2      0.00    2      0.00    2
                 MIN     3.29    1     38.36    1      0.00    2      0.00    2
     STAAD SPACE                                              -- PAGE NO.    7

           2.46  MAX    14.79    2     54.51    2      0.00    2      0.00    2
                 MIN     9.86    1     36.34    1      0.00    2      0.00    2
           2.77  MAX    24.65    2     48.44    2      0.00    2      0.00    2
                 MIN    16.43    1     32.29    1      0.00    2      0.00    2
           3.08  MAX    34.51    2     39.34    2      0.00    2      0.00    2
                 MIN    23.00    1     26.23    1      0.00    2      0.00    2
           3.38  MAX    44.37    2     27.20    2      0.00    2      0.00    2
                 MIN    29.58    1     18.14    1      0.00    2      0.00    2
           3.69  MAX    54.23    2     12.04    2      0.00    2      0.00    2
                 MIN    36.15    1      8.02    1      0.00    2      0.00    2
           4.00  MAX    42.72    1      4.11    1      0.00    2      0.00    2
                 MIN    64.08    2      6.17    2      0.00    2      0.00    2
```

But the output which I want is like as shown below:-

```
     2     0.00  MAX    64.08    2      6.17    2      0.00    2      0.00    2
                 MIN    42.72    1      4.11    1      0.00    2      0.00    2
           0.31  MAX    54.23    2     12.04    2      0.00    2      0.00    2
                 MIN    36.15    1      8.02    1      0.00    2      0.00    2
           0.62  MAX    44.37    2     27.20    2      0.00    2      0.00    2
                 MIN    29.58    1     18.14    1      0.00    2      0.00    2
           0.92  MAX    34.51    2     39.34    2      0.00    2      0.00    2
                 MIN    23.00    1     26.23    1      0.00    2      0.00    2
           1.23  MAX    24.65    2     48.44    2      0.00    2      0.00    2
                 MIN    16.43    1     32.29    1      0.00    2      0.00    2
           1.54  MAX    14.79    2     54.51    2      0.00    2      0.00    2
                 MIN     9.86    1     36.34    1      0.00    2      0.00    2
           1.85  MAX     4.93    2     57.54    2      0.00    2      0.00    2
                 MIN     3.29    1     38.36    1      0.00    2      0.00    2
           2.15  MAX     4.93    2     57.54    2      0.00    2      0.00    2
                 MIN     3.29    1     38.36    1      0.00    2      0.00    2
           2.46  MAX    14.79    2     54.51    2      0.00    2      0.00    2
                 MIN     9.86    1     36.34    1      0.00    2      0.00    2
           2.77  MAX    24.65    2     48.44    2      0.00    2      0.00    2
                 MIN    16.43    1     32.29    1      0.00    2      0.00    2
           3.08  MAX    34.51    2     39.34    2      0.00    2      0.00    2
                 MIN    23.00    1     26.23    1      0.00    2      0.00    2
           3.38  MAX    44.37    2     27.20    2      0.00    2      0.00    2
                 MIN    29.58    1     18.14    1      0.00    2      0.00    2
           3.69  MAX    54.23    2     12.04    2      0.00    2      0.00    2
                 MIN    36.15    1      8.02    1      0.00    2      0.00    2
           4.00  MAX    42.72    1      4.11    1      0.00    2      0.00    2
                 MIN    64.08    2      6.17    2      0.00    2      0.00    2
     3     0.00  MAX    64.08    2      6.17    2      0.00    2      0.00    2
                 MIN    42.72    1      4.11    1      0.00    2      0.00    2
           0.31  MAX    54.23    2     12.04    2      0.00    2      0.00    2
                 MIN    36.15    1      8.02    1      0.00    2      0.00    2
           0.62  MAX    44.37    2     27.20    2      0.00    2      0.00    2
                 MIN    29.58    1     18.14    1      0.00    2      0.00    2
           0.92  MAX    34.51    2     39.34    2      0.00    2      0.00    2
                 MIN    23.00    1     26.23    1      0.00    2      0.00    2
           1.23  MAX    24.65    2     48.44    2      0.00    2      0.00    2
                 MIN    16.43    1     32.29    1      0.00    2      0.00    2
           1.54  MAX    14.79    2     54.51    2      0.00    2      0.00    2
                 MIN     9.86    1     36.34    1      0.00    2      0.00    2
           1.85  MAX     4.93    2     57.54    2      0.00    2      0.00    2
                 MIN     3.29    1     38.36    1      0.00    2      0.00    2
           2.15  MAX     4.93    2     57.54    2      0.00    2      0.00    2
                 MIN     3.29    1     38.36    1      0.00    2      0.00    2
           2.46  MAX    14.79    2     54.51    2      0.00    2      0.00    2
                 MIN     9.86    1     36.34    1      0.00    2      0.00    2
           2.77  MAX    24.65    2     48.44    2      0.00    2      0.00    2
                 MIN    16.43    1     32.29    1      0.00    2      0.00    2
           3.08  MAX    34.51    2     39.34    2      0.00    2      0.00    2
                 MIN    23.00    1     26.23    1      0.00    2      0.00    2
           3.38  MAX    44.37    2     27.20    2      0.00    2      0.00    2
                 MIN    29.58    1     18.14    1      0.00    2      0.00    2
           3.69  MAX    54.23    2     12.04    2      0.00    2      0.00    2
                 MIN    36.15    1      8.02    1      0.00    2      0.00    2
           4.00  MAX    42.72    1      4.11    1      0.00    2      0.00    2
                 MIN    64.08    2      6.17    2      0.00    2      0.00    2
```

Comment: Have you tried using regex?

Comment: Could you provide more information about the text file so that other people can have a comprehensive view of your problem?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a shortened sample of your `3d_frame.txt` file that recreates your problem. Also include the expected output that you are trying to get.